# How to limit file's size and mimetype on upload to S3

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url, file-storage

On my application I save all user's images on Amazon S3.
I'm realizing a web interface for uploading images to S3.

On my nodejs backend I'm creating presigned post request:

```
const presignedPostParams = ({ userId }) => ({
  Bucket: bucket,
  Conditions: [
    ['starts-with', '$key', `user/${userId}/`],
  ],
  Expires: 60 * 5,
});

  const request = await createPresignedPost(presignedPostParams({ userId }));
```

On my frontend I'm sending a form to S3 with presigned params.

It works.

But now I can upload any files, not only images. I want to limit file types to upload (mimetypes)? Of course, I can limit it by javascript code on front. By it is not reliable.

Can I limit file mimetype while I'm creating presigned url?

And the second question: can I manage the permission of uploaded file from presigned url? I want upload some public and some private files from one interface (maybe I can realize this with presigned url?)

Comment: I found some similar code that contained the condition `["starts-with", "$Content-Type", ""]`, so I suspect you could insert a specific content type in there.

Comment: Thank you. I'm sending post request to S3 by axios. Content-type is always 'application/json' (because I'm sending form, where only one field is file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got the answer to the second question.

It's very easy, but I haven't found it in the documentation.

I added one condition to the backend (about this I read on docs):

```
  Conditions: [
    { acl: 'public-read' },
    // ...
  ],
```

and added one field to the frontend: *'acl': 'public-read'*

(I found it by chance surfing by links on POST Policy documentation )

---

About file's size:
Its easy, too:
You should add one condition: *["content-length-range", 1048579, 10485760]*

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can utilize a Presigned POST and define a [POST policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-HTTPPOSTConstructPolicy.html) to add functionality to restrict file size and mime type, as well as other areas of concern.